Open PDF file using link button in a new browser/window on ASP.NET & VB.NET
I have a link button that has an image, where if I click it, it needs to open a .pdf file in a new tab/window. I added the PDF file to my code folder. I'm not sure if this is right. But definitely I got an error. So maybe someone can point me to the right direction on how to do this properly.
This is the error I got:

Error BC30456: 'window' is not a member of 'ASP.sform_aspx'

This is my code:
<div style="float:right;">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnMap" runat="server" style="text-decoration:none;"
         OnClick="window.open('~\Content\ManagementZonesMap.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=no');">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/MapIcon.jpg" Height="40%" Width="40%" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>  


Webforms? Please specify which version of ASP.NET!

Hi! Yes in webform.

Added to the tags.

The OnClick attribute and ~ prefix are server-side constructs,  but window.open() is client-side JavaScript code.
JavaScript events are case-sensitive, and while it's sometimes fine to put JavaScript onclick events into ASP .NET controls, you're generally better off using OnClientClick().
You'll also need to be careful with the ~ relative path reference, as it's only valid in places where the server can process path first.

This resolved the error. May I ask, it opens to a new tab but how do I make it if I want a new window(a separate one)?
